# swift array.firstIndex(where: ...) index out of range ... but why?

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

here are some lines of code

```
            print ("dayNumber: \(dayNumber)")
            print ("all: \(self.RKINumbersOfDays)")
            print ("kindOf: \(kindOf): \(self.RKINumbersOfDays[kindOf])")

            let indexToUse: Int
            if let foundIndex = self.RKINumbersOfDays.firstIndex(where: { $0[kindOf] < dayNumber } ) {
                indexToUse = foundIndex
            } else {
                indexToUse = 0
            }
```

which gives this output

```
dayNumber: 7316
all: [[7316], [7316], [7316], [7316]]
kindOf: 1: [7316]
Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
2021-01-12 23:12:29.720561+0100 CoBaT[7595:6310152] Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
(lldb)
```

and in debug mode the line "if let foundIndex = self.RKINumbersOfDays.firstIndex(where ..." is marked red with "Fatal error: index out of range"

But why???

EDIT:
well, sometimes "you don't see the forrest, because of all the trees" ;-)

of course: the right syntax is:

```
self.RKINumbersOfDays[kindOf].firstIndex(where: { $0 < dayNumber }
```

and that works very well ...

Comment: What index are you using? `1`?

Comment: the index will be set in the if let statement.. I used this construct many times without any problems .. so far ;-) ... all variables are printed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `kindOf`  here

```
print ("kindOf: \(kindOf): \(self.RKINumbersOfDays[kindOf])")
```

is for the main array count ( `RKINumbersOfDays` ) while here it's for sub elements count

```
$0[kindOf] < dayNumber
```

that one of them has a count that's less than `kindOf` ( here all has a count of 1 so max index should be 0 not 1 )

Comment: the right syntax is: "self.RKINumbersOfDays[kindOf].firstIndex(where: { $0 < dayNumber } )"